# How do I put a computer outside of a NAT, giving it a separate IP address?

Tags: networking, router, dns, nat

I have two servers running behind my D-Link DIR-655 NAT router. Obviously, I cannot allow outside access to both of them simultaneously without putting them on different external ports, which I don't want to do. (DNS can only redirect to the common external IP of my router, not the unique internal IPs of my servers.) The easiest solution I can think of to this is simply to put one of the servers completely outside of the router so that it grabs its own IP address from Comcast (and thus allows me to change my DNS records so that the destination IPs are different.) Is this possible, and if it is, how do I do it?

P.S. I've already tried putting one server into the DMZ (Demilitarized Zone) on my router to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately what you are after is not possible. Unless you are paying for multiple static IP addresses from Comcast (Comcast Business plan), Comcast will only supply you with one WAN IP address. Your only option is to run the servers on separate ports.

That said, if the servers you are hosting are HTTP (Web) servers, you can setup a "reverse proxy" that, depending on the hostname of the requested page, will route the incoming connections to the correct server. It is pretty easy to setup an Apache2 reverse proxy; do some research.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use multiple IPs then there are 2 solutions: VPN or IPv6

Basically IPv6 doesn't use NAT anymore so your interfaces are now exposing directly to the internet and will have a separate public IPv6 address. With VPN your PC(s) will act as they're in the same LAN as the gateway. So by connecting your servers to different VPNs they'll have different public IPv4 addresses, but of course you must choose a VPN provider that supports port forwarding in order for the servers to receive connections